# How do you convert an int byte colour value (0-255) into a float / double value (0-1) in C#?

Tags: c#, colors

It says how to convert float color values into byte color values everywhere, I want to know how to do the opposite, anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to divide byte value by 255.

```
double d = (double)byteValue / 255
```